# Select multiple columns by character using Like

Tags: python, pandas

From a data frame with multiple columns, I need to select those columns which contain only the characters 'Id' and 'ndvi'.I have no problem with selecting only those columns containing 'Id' or 'ndvi' alone, problem arise when combining both criteria. 
Thank you very much for your help!

So far I've been using ndvi=df.filter(like='ndvi') or ndvi2=df.filter(like='Id')

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to select those columns which contain only the characters 'Id' and 'ndvi'

If it means is necessary select only columns `ndvi` and `Id`:

```
both = df[['ndvi','Id']]
```

If need to test subtrings with values `ndvi` or `Id` use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with `regex` parameter and `ndvi|Id` with `|` for regex or:

```
both = df.filter(regex='ndvi|Id')
```

Comment: Great! both = df.filter(regex='ndvi|Id')  That worked! Thank you very much!